# how to fix SystemCheckError

Tags: python, django

Hi while I was adding a dislike button to my blog I encountered a SystemCheckError. How do I fix it. I hope someone can help me.

Traceback:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
myblog.Post.dislike: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'myblog.Post.dislike' clashes with reverse accessor for 'myblog.Post.likes'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'myblog.Post.dislike' or 'myblog.Post.likes'.
myblog.Post.dislike: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'myblog.Post.dislike' clashes with reverse query name for 'myblog.Post.likes'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'myblog.Post.dislike' or 'myblog.Post.likes'.
myblog.Post.likes: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'myblog.Post.likes' clashes with reverse accessor for 'myblog.Post.dislike'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'myblog.Post.likes' or 'myblog.Post.dislike'.
myblog.Post.likes: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'myblog.Post.likes' clashes with reverse query name for 'myblog.Post.dislike'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'myblog.Post.likes' or 'myblog.Post.dislike'.

WARNINGS:
myblog.Category: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the MyblogConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
myblog.Post: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the MyblogConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
```

Models.py

```
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post')
dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post')
```

If any other file is needed please do ask.

Comment: `HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'myblog.Post.dislike' or 'myblog.Post.likes'.` You're using the same `related_name` for two different fields.

Comment: Soo, what do I do exactly @crissal.

Comment: > You're using the same `related_name` for two different fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post')
dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post')
```

to

```
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_likes')
dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_dislikes')
```